# ArrayList of string and another arraylist

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, polymorphism, hierarchy

so i'm making a program to manage a book store, heres an example of whats supposed to do with the the following main:

```
        bookStore bookStore = new bookStore("Lelo");
        book l1 = new TecnicalBook("H. Schildt", "\"Java: The Complete Reference\"", 80, "Computer Science- Java");
        bookStore.addBook(l1);
        book l2= new AdventureBook("A. Christie", "\"The Man in the Brown Suit\"", 75, 14);
        bookStore.addBook(l2);
                
        
        Client c1 = new Premium("B. Antunes", "antunes@books.com");
        bookStore.addClient(c1);
        Client c2 = new Frequent("A. Oliveira", "oliveira@books.com");
        bookStore.addClient(c2);
        System.out.println("Initial stock:");
        bookStore.showBooks();
        bookStore.sale(l1, c1);
        System.out.println("Stock after selling:");
        bookStore.showBooks();
        System.out.println("Sales Volume:"+bookStore.SalesVolume);        
        bookStore.showClientsBooks(c1);
```

Should show this result:

```
Initial stock:
Author:H. Schildt   Title:"Java: The Complete Reference"   Base Price:80.0
Author:A. Christie   Title:"The Man in the Brown Suit"   Base Price:75.0
B. Antunes bought "Java: The Complete Reference", Tecnical Book of Computer Science- Java, for 72.0
Stock after selling:
Author:A. Christie   Title:"The Man in the Brown Suit"   Base Price:75.0
Sales Volume:72.0
B. Antunes bought: "UML Distilled". "The Man in the Brown Suit".
```

The only part that i cant do is the last line, showing the products that each client has bought, i was thinking of making an class that contained a string with the clients name and an arraylist of a book class, and then having an array list of that class for each client, but i'm not sure how to make this and theres probably a better way,
Thanks

edit: i have this classes:
class book
class tecnicalbook extends book
class adventurebook extends book

class client
class regular extends client
class frequent extends client
class premium extends client

and i have the bookstore class where i have an array list of book and client objects.

Comment: I think the solution you suggested is fine!

Comment: @Laugslander so lets say that i create an a arrayList of clientBooks class with an String of the clients name and an arrayList of book objects, how do i then add the books that an client bought and how do i print all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a list of Books to your Client class to keep track of sales:

```
class Client {

    ...

    private List<Book> books;

    ClientBooks(Client client) {
        ...

        this.books = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        this.books.add(book);
    }

    public void printBooks() {
        for (Book book : this.books) {
            System.out.println(book);
        }
    }
}
```

Selling a book can be implemented like this:

```
List<Client> clients = ...

String buyer = ...
Book book = ...

for(Client client : clients) {
    if (client.getName().equals(buyer)) {
        client.addBook(book);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i, when selling a book to a client, add it to the array list sprecific to that client?

Comment: If you keep track of a list of ClientBooks, you can iterate over this list and check for each element of the name of the client matches. If so, you can call the addBooks method.

Comment: So i would have to iterate the arraylist containing the ClientBooks objects, and find the Client that i want and then, print the books array list, how can i do this?

Comment: Refer to my edited answer for a suggestion on how to implement this.

Comment: Sorry but just another question, how can i then show the prducts that each client as bought? For example if i put  bookStore.printClientBooks(c1) it prints the books that c1 as bought

Comment: You can reuse the second part of my answer. Instead of calling the addBooks method, you can call the printBooks method to print the books the client bought.

Comment: Can i send you a dm?

Comment: Your design does not make sense. It would be better design to have a client Class and have that class hold a list of books for that client.  You could then have a list of Client objects.  Consider this.  You must have a ClientBooks class per client.  So you must already know which client it is to retreive it.   So why have anything in that class returning information you already have.

Comment: @josilva00  No need to send a dm.  This site has sophisticated chat capability.  And you can set up private chats that only you and selected individuals can participate in (selected individuals also includes moderators of course). Click the icon in the upper right corner of this screen.  You should see a chat menu option.

Comment: I've went with @WJS advice and i found it a bit easier to understand and to aply, i've finished the program,thanks to you both.

Comment: I also agree with @WJS comment and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Laugslander - great +1

Answer (score 0):

It is important to override `toString` in each class.  Then when your print the instance of that class, the string will print instead of some strange value.

This method also allows you to add all the books at once or individual books if you choose.

This class has not been tested but it should give you an idea of how to procede.

```
class Client {
  String name;
  private List<Book> clientBooks = new ArrayList<>();
  public Client(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }

  public addBooks(List<Book> books) {
      clientBooks.addAll(books);
  }

  public void addBook(Book bk) {
      clientBooks.add(bk);
  }

  public String toString() {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name).append(":");
     // add either the entire toString for book here or just selected
     // items like the title.  It's up to you.
     for (Book b :clientBooks) {
        sb.append(b.toString()).append(", ");
     }
     
     return sb.toString().substring(0,sb.length()-2);
  }
}
```